# Basic inequality related to semigroup property

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, semigroup-of-operators

Let $T$ be a one parameter semigroup on Banach space $X$. We know that $T$ has the property 
$$T(t+s)=T(t)T(s)\quad\text{for all}\quad t,s\ge 0. $$

I was reading some notes on evolution equations and I was told that the above property implies that

1. $T(t)=T\left(\frac{t}{n+1}\right)^{n+1}$ and
2. $\|T(t)\|\le \|T\left(\frac{t}{n+1}\right)\|^{n+1}$

Now my questions are, first, I do not understand the stated property leads to 1.
Next, I do not see how 1. leads to 2.

Appreciate for any help

Comment: Have you even tried?

Comment: Write down what (1) is for $n = 1$. Then try to prove it.

Comment: @HansEngler Could you also give me some hint to prove 2?

Comment: Now I am fine with 1 using induction. Will write it out...

Comment: Remember that for bounded linear operators $A,B$ the inequality holds $\|AB\| \le \|A\| \|B\|$.

Comment: yes, quite clear...I shall answer my own question soon

Answer (score 0):

First, we prove the fact 
$T(t)=T\left(\frac{t}{n+1}\right)^{n+1}$ by induction.
First, we show the property hold for the case $n=1$, i.e. $T(t)=T\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)^{2}$. The right hand side is
\begin{equation*}
 T\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)T\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)=T(t)
\end{equation*}
equals the left hand side.

Now assume it is true for $n=k$, where $k\ge 2$, we want to show it logically follows that $n=k+1$ is true. So again start with the right hand side we have 
\begin{align*}
 \underbrace{T\left(\frac{t}{k+1}\right)\cdots T\left(\frac{t}{k+1}\right)}_{k} T\left(\frac{t}{k+1}\right)
 &= T\left(\frac{t}{k+1}\right)^k  T\left(\frac{t}{k+1}\right)\\
 &=T\left(\frac{t}{k+1}\right)^{k+1}=T(t)
\end{align*}
and so the result 1 follows.

Now using the fact $\|AB\|\le \|A\|\|B\|$, we have
\begin{align*}
 &\ \left\|\underbrace{T\left(\frac{t}{k+1}\right)\cdots T\left(\frac{t}{k+1}\right)}_{k+1}\right\|\\
 &\ \le\underbrace{ \left\|T\left(\frac{t}{k+1}\right)\right\|\cdot\left\|T\left(\frac{t}{k+1}\right)\right\|\cdots \left\|T\left(\frac{t}{k+1}\right)\right\|}_{k+1}
\end{align*}
and so the result 2 follows.